# What is the maximum object size before GAE throws Heap overflow error

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I never thought of this until now, I have been using GAE for quite some time already--but never think of its memory model, since its JVM is there already, I can't say which JVM or version of JVM they are using.

So my question would be when will GAE throw Heap overflow error? Or at least would break my app or whatvever the GAE will do. I don't know.

For example, I push the `String` to the limits that I put a data with sizeof `2^31 -1`

**Design wise:** I know this is crazy, but the idea is the same with having millions or billions or users pushing data into your GAE application, then your application's job is to process it (serialize/deserialize) before persisting.

Then the heap sum of those will be huge, they might not happen all at the same time, but for sure there will be a tangent point where heap use will be huge.

Is this something that GAE application have to be concered with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read more on [Adjusting Application Performance](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/performancesettings) for your running application based on your needs and from the same link you can see the memory and CPU that each front end class has.

Answer (score 0):

You need to code it so you will never run oom independent of user load. If you allow mutithread your instance might get reused and you need to take that into account. If mem, cpu or queue  is too high appengine automatically will launch  more instances each with their own ram , specified in app settings (128mb, 256mb etc)

Answer (score 0):

An application on GAE is distributed across many, many instances.  If you're handling millions of simultaneous users, you'll probably running thousands of instances.  Each instance has its RAM (stack + heap space).

Your total heap may be huge, but at any one point, you only need to manage the heap for the requests running on a particular instance, which can only handle a fairly limited number of requests at once.  For the memory sizes for different instance types, refer to:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/performancesettings?hl=en